# (How) Should I move a question from Math SE to Physics SE?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, migration

I asked a math question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4475036/342834 in an area where physicists are likely to have a great deal of practical background.  I had originally intended to post the Physics SE, but forgot to switch communities.  I believe posting the same question to both communities is frowned upon.  **If** I wanted to move this question to the physics community, how should I do it?

Comment: IMO that question is better on Math SE than PSE. I say just keep it there

Comment: Yes, as others have indicated, that question is probably better (more likely to get a good answer) at the Math site than Physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the *flag* link under your question and choose the option *In need of moderator attention*, then leave a message for the mods asking to migrate the question.

However it isn't clear to me whether the question would be better here. Maybe give it a few days where it is and request a migration if you don't get and answer on the Math SE.